# I am trying to decrypt a .pgp file given the .asc file

Tags: gnupg

i have a file.txt.pgp which i want to decrypt in solaris. i have a key.asc file as well.

I imported the key using

> gpg --import key.asc

when i am trying to decrpty the file using

> > gpg --decrypt file.txt.pgp

I am getting the below error
gpg:no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg:decrypt message failed:eof

Also there is no secret/private key corresponding to the public key i imported. How can i fix this?